# Convert string into date format in R

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to convert a string into a date format "yyy-mm-dd" in R programming using below steps:

date<- as.Date(S, "%Y- %m- %d")

where S is a vector containing a string value "15082022"

But above method is not giving an output in the format yyy-mm-dd.

Can someone advise the correct command for this

Comment: try `as.Date("15081022", "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: Thanks for checking. Actually, it is calling the value of S via a function

Comment: Is "15081022" supposed to be "15082022"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as.Date()` function will convert a string into date format, and the format of the output will always be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format in R (ISO 8601). The `format` argument in the `as.Date()` function is to specify the date format of the string input. I remember I initially thought it was specifying the output format, but it's the input format (you can change the output format with a subsequent `format()` function, however this will convert it back to a string).

Your string looks to be in `ddmmyyyy` (`%d%m%Y`) format, this should be what you specify as the format argument in `as.Date()`. Your format does not include hyphens, so the `format` argument should also not include hyphens. Note that `ddmmyyyy`, `dd-mm-yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd.mm.yyyy` are all different date formats, even though the day, month and year are in the same order, they would be converted to date with formats `%d%m%Y`, `%d-%m-%Y`, `%d/%m/%Y`, and `%d.%m.%Y`, respectively.

Further advice on working with dates and times is available in the relevant chapters of [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html) by Wickham & Grolemund and [The R Cookbook](https://rc2e.com/stringsanddates#recipe-id043) by Teetor & Long.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help.