# Converting string vector to date

Tags: r, string, date

I have below vector of string

```
dates = c('1997 Jan- 6', '1997 Jan-13')
```

I wish I could have a generic approach so that I can get a `date` vector from this string.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Thanks for your insight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string into date format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755258/convert-string-into-date-format-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ymd`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(dates)
[1] "1997-01-06" "1997-01-13"
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
 as.Date(dates, format = '%Y %b-%d')
[1] "1997-01-06" "1997-01-13"
```